# Using .body = ActiveDocument. to pull in only a portion of a Word document

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

As you can see from the code (tied to a command button in a Word 2016 document) I have right now, the command button will:

1. launch/display an email
2. Adds ALL the document contents to the body of an email (via .Body = ActiveDocument.Content)
3. Attach the Word doc

Question: Is there a way to only pull in portions of the document content into the body? Basically, I have a form that will be filled out by employees. After (below) the form, there are some instructions on how to complete the form, some definitions, and other administrative information that I would rather NOT be pulled into the body of the email.

Current code:

```
Dim OL   As Object
Dim EmailItem   As Object
Dim Doc   As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument

Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = "test subject line"
    .Body = ActiveDocument.Content
    .To = "myemail@email.com"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Display
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.Body` property contains a string. `ActiveDocument.Content` is a string which comprises the entire document. Technically, any smaller part of the document is also a string. Therefore you can pick any part of the document and assign it to the `.Body` property.
This link may help you pick the part of the document you wish to include in your email. [VBA to copy text from excel to on specific location in wordfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351308/vba-to-copy-text-from-excel-to-on-specific-location-in-wordfile)
The code to use would be

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Excerpt As String

' Find the range with guidance from the above link
Excerpt = Rng.Text
EmailItem.Body = Excerpt
```