# How to copy text into word using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How to paste a particular text into word at a particular location and header as well using VBA in excel. As of now, I can open the word using excel and I have got few things on to word using Excel VBA.

```
  Sub Open_word()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim filepath As String

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    filepath = "https://sharepoint.lamrc.net/cft/edms/Documents/DDS2011.doc"
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(filepath)
    '----------------------Downloads document----------------------


    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbCrLf
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbCrLf
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbCrLf
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbCrLf

    wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Content.Delete



    '----------------------Deletes default content----------------------

    Dim strNewFolderName As String
    strNewFolderName = "New Folder " & (Day(Now())) & "_" & Month(Now()) & "_" & Year(Now)
    If Len(Dir("C:\Macro_test\" & strNewFolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir ("C:\Macro_test\" & strNewFolderName)
    End If
    Dim PathName As String
    PathName = ("New Folder " & MonthName(Month(Now())) & " " & Year(Now))

    wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\macro_test\" & strNewFolderName & "\" & "test" + ".doc"

    '----------------------save as files----------------------


    Sheets("SCREW").Range("H1:J11").Copy
    wrdApp.Selection.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '------------- pastes the actual content--------------


    Set wrdApp = Nothing

    Set wrdDoc = Nothing

    MsgBox ("DONE")

    '----------------message box---------------

  End Sub'
```

I'm able to copy the conten to word but not able to copy it to particular location.

Please help.

Comment: Have a look around. Similar questions have been asked before. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351308/vba-to-copy-text-from-excel-to-on-specific-location-in-wordfile)

Comment: Please be specific about "particular location". Your requirement is unclear.

Comment: You might also want to review what your code is doing. I can't see any point in any of your 'ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = vbCrLf' lines, given that you follow those with 'wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Content.Delete', which also makes me wonder why you're opening an existing document only to delete all its content...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this as an answer: this is because I don't have enough Karma Points to make this a comment.

If you are going to use a similar document all of the time then I would actually create a template with bookmarks in.   Then create a document based on that template.

This then gives you a document of the right format and then all you have to do is to shove in some code such as:

```
wrdDoc.Bookmarks("bmkScrewData").Range.Text = Sheets("SCREW").Range("H1:J11")
```

Assuming that you have a bookmark called bmkScrewData.   It's miles easier just to open a document based on a template then try to force stuff into a blank document.  This way you can have your environment completely under your control.

It also means that you can avoid all the deletion of the default gubbins in the new Word document.

Comment: I'm not using the same word file, it keeps pulling from internet each now.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to work out how the relevant locations might be identified (e.g. paragraph x, or a particular string that's always in the same relative location).

Comment: Looking at the code, though, I am wondering if the document is a blank document: this coming from the deletion.   So, if this is the case, then why isn't the document based on a template and then saved to the remote location?

Comment: @macropod Thanks for the comment.How do i identify the particular paragraph position?

Comment: @Shoeless Basically it is a word template which is stored in a intranet, I download it and delete few guidelines which are already present in the template and try putting the data which is in excel using macro but it gets pasted on the top of document instead I want it to be pasted in particular location.

Comment: @SujayM You previously said "I'm not using the same word file", but now you say "it is a word template which is stored in a intranet". If so, it *is* the same Word file. Moreover, you should be using Documents.Add, not Documents.Open. Regardless, you have to identify where to add content. I already gave you suggestions for that. And, since it is the same document, you could also use bookmarks, tables, content controls, and so on, as appropriate, that you've added to it as placeholders before running your code. This is all basic Word VBA and there are many examples here for you to look at.

Comment: If it's a template (.dot or .dotx) then it's dead easy,.

All you do is to create a document based on that template (it's best to have a local copy of the template on your machine first: have a login script download the templates each log in, for example) and then immediately save to your desired destination.

Then whilst you have the document initially saved then start to put the data into the required positions, i.e. bookmarks, in the document.

Save again and, voila, job done.